# How does tabling improve efficiency?

Tags: prolog, logic-programming, prolog-tabling

I am curious about how tabling works to improve efficiency of Prolog programs.  How is it implemented?  Both explanation and references are welcome.

Comment: [doc](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.5123v1.pdf) from gurus... I think it answers your question really in depth...

Comment: From David Warren (one of the authors from the posted paper) a good/introductory (with excellent working examples), although not very recent publication on Programming in Tabled Prolog: http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~warren/xsbbook/node1.html

Comment: B-Prolog Documentation "Section 16.2 Linear tabling and the strategies" is also usefui, you can find it here: http://www.picat-lang.org/bprolog/download/manual.pdf

Comment: Check out: https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/memoization